# First value of select2 is not shown when using the i18next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2, i18next

I'm doing the internationalization with the lib i18next , all right occurs, it translates puts the values ​​within the `select2` , but the first value is not shown in any way , even if I open the `select2` and clicking on the first item. Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head><title>Select2</title></head>
<body>
   <div>
      <label class="col-sm-12 text-white" style="text-align: left;" data-i18n="store.tipo"> </label>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <select id="selectTipo" class="form-control"></select>
         <br/>
         <br/>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script src="~/lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="~/lib/select2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="~/js/arquivo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         GetTipo();
      })
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript: **(arquivo.js)**

```
function GetTipo(){
var $selectTipo = $('#selectTipo');

$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.todos">', { value: "0", text: $(this).data('data-i18n')}));
$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.painel">', { value: "1", text: $(this).data('data-i18n') }));
$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.report">', { value: "2", text: $(this).data('data-i18n') }));
$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.notificacao">', { value: "3", text: $(this).data('data-i18n') }));
$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.auditoria">', { value: "4", text: $(this).data('data-i18n') }));
$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.apresentacao">', { value: "5", text: $(this).data('data-i18n') }));
$selectTipo.val("0").trigger("change");
$selectTipo.select2();
}
```

IMAGEM:

[image]

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/danpadua/bq92ufq3/4/

Comment: Few remarks to your code. You are trying `$(this).data('data-i18n')` for each `.append()`, but as far as I can see the `GetTipo()` function will be scoped to **window** scope, literally say `$(window).data('data-i18n')` will always return almost nothing. + `change` event will be fired anyway after setting new `.val()`. Moreover, when using `.data()` you don't need to write full attribute name, just part without `data-` prefix.

Comment: Resolved in other link pt-BR http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91104/primeiro-valor-do-select2-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-mostrado-quando-usa-o-i18next/91158#91158